# Idea : Generate multiple http response using a single http request

Tags: http, httprequest, httpresponse

I would like to know your view/comments regarding this concept. If an alternative is available? And if this would be feasible/beneficial?

As per my understanding, for every http request, the server performs some operation and sends back a http response.

Now consider any scenario, where we want to have more control over the process running on the server.

**Situation 1** : http request send -> server start processing (long task in process) -> user closes the browser.
Here the process still executes, consuming the server and http response will be ignored at the client.

Here resources are wasted.

**Situation 2** : http request send -> server starts processing (long task in process)

Here the client is unaware of the status of the process running in the server.
The client has to wait till it  gets back the http response.

*My Idea : In between the initial http request and final http response, add a feature to send multiple intermediate http responses, that will carry information regarding the process running at the server end.*

**Solution to Situation 1** : http request send -> server start processing (long task in process) -> [ return the process id as an intermediate http response] -> user closes the browser -> [ send an http request to closes the server process using the process id]

**Solution to Situation 2** : http request send -> server starts processing (long task in process) -> [return http responses with details of the process running at the server at intervals] -> [perform any operation if required]

Kindly comment :) and correct if I'm missing anything.

Comment: This is commonly done by returning 202 Accepted with a `Location` header telling you where to go look for the results. If you want an ongoing update, use WebSockets. Defining your own HTTP is probably not an effective route forwards, and SO can't really help you with that process anyway; we aren't in charge of the protocol.

Comment: This sounds clean and simple. Go, implement it.

Comment: @RolandIllig I don't think it's particularly constructive to send the OP off with a "go do it" when they clearly don't comprehend the magnitude of the task.

Comment: For a better idea of the sheer quantity of process involved read up on the last change to HTTP, to 2.0: https://http2.github.io/faq/

Comment: Then maybe I also didn't understand the magnitude. To me it sounded like a `POST /start-longrunning-task`, which would return `12345`, followed by several `GET /task-status/12345`. This, in my mind, makes a nice API for long-running tasks.

Comment: Those GETs would be separate requests and responses, though, this is supported (and, as I comment above, used with an initial 202) by current HTTP. What the OP appears to be proposing is a new part of the protocol, which will involve RFCs, the IETF and W3C and updates to browser and server software.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you have understood the idea. Just wanted to know if such feature exists in http and if something like this would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

For "Situation 2", you should have a look at informational responses; see https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#status.1xx.